# Is there a way to have a generic type constraint that is also generic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

I'm trying to create a generic container class to contain a list of generic types but I am unable to express it syntactically in c#.

This code uses a bit of game engine API (Unity) so it might help to ignore the ScriptableObject, SerializedField or the reason why I need to extend the generic classes to begin with.

This is the code I have:

```
public class RankUnlockedItemBase<T> : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField] private int acquiredRankPoints;
    public int AcquiredRankPoints { get => acquiredRankPoints; }
    [SerializeField] private T item;
    public T Item => item;

    public bool IsUnlocked(int rankPoints)
    {
        return rankPoints > acquiredRankPoints;
    }
}
```

Here's what an implementation looks like:

```
public class RankUnlockedInt : RankUnlockedItemBase<int> { }
```

Here's the generic container class where I derived my question from. The generic RankUnlockedItemContainer with a type constraint of generic type RankUnlockedItemBase:

```
public class RankUnlockedItemContainer<T> : ScriptableObject where T : RankUnlockedItemBase<?> // Im lost here
{
    [SerializeField] private List<T> items;
    public List<T> Items {get => items; }

    public List<T> GetAllUnlockedItemsUpToRank(int rank)
    {
        List<T> unlockedItems = new List<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].IsUnlocked(rank))
            {
                unlockedItems.Add(items[i]);
            }
        }

        return unlockedItems;
    }
}
```

Here's what I guess I was aiming to achieve for an implementation

```
public class RankUnlockedIntContainer : RankUnlockedItemContainer<RankUnlockedInt> { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could have two generic types

```
public abstract class RankUnlockedItemContainer<TItem, TValue> : ScriptableObject : where TItem : RankUnlockedItemBase<TValue> { ... }
```

And implement e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class RankUnlockedIntContainer : RankUnlockedItemContainer<RankUnlockedInt, int> { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This solves my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Use two generic type parameters. One `TList` for your list and a second `Titem` for the type in `RankUnlockedItemBase`.

```
public class RankUnlockedItemContainer<TList, TItem> : ScriptableObject where TList : RankUnlockedItemBase<TItem> {}
```

Of course your can derive your container types explicitly.

```
public class RankUnlockedIntContainer : RankUnlockedItemContainer<RankUnlockedInt, int> {}
```

However, if you *do not change* their implementation apart from the concrete types, you can instantiate containers without deriving sub types. Think of `List<T>`, why derive a type for each item type?

```
var container = new RankUnlockedItemContainer<RankUnlockedInt, int>();
```

Comment: Fantastic! This solves my problem. I'm not sure how to explain it exactly, but in the game engine I use, you can create these asset files (scriptable objects) which you can change data on via an interface (so for example I could just assign a value to an int in the editor instead of the code). You cannot however show generic types in the editor, so you have to drill down into a concretion which is what I'm doing with these derived classes. Hope that makes some sense!

Comment: BTW I think u meant similar to what derHugo meant with TItem, Tvalue